# Mesos Performance Overhead

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I'm working on developing some Docker containers to run in a Mesos cluster. We're doing job submission via Chronos which is managed by Marathon. However, I noticed a significant performance decrease when running my containers in Mesos vs. executing them directly via Docker. Normally, these containers could do the job in about 1.5 minutes, but I've seen times ranging form 3-12 minutes when running with Mesos. The core process I'm running does a lot of disk I/O, so perhaps there's something with how I/O is handled in Mesos that's causing this?

Any thoughts would be great, though just in case someone suggests it, I can't change the core process that's run. I don't have control over it and it's quite complex.

Thanks.

EDIT: Did some additional testing with just running the job through Marathon and performance is as expected.  Perhaps it's Chronos that's causing this degradation?  If so, why would that be?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. Both, Chronos and Marathon simply send a TaskInfo to Mesos. Mesos then simply runs the same docker command a user would run. Do you have different hosts? Can you see a difference in execution time when running it on different hosts?

Comment: Yes, I have several hosts that it run on, but regardless of the host, I only see a difference when submitting the job through Chronos.

Comment: Did you configure the same amount of resources in all cases?

Comment: During later testing, yes.

Comment: Can you share what happened later? Have you found out why? Or workaround maybe?

Comment: @Dincer Unfortunately, no, I can't.  It's been quite a while since I looked into this and we have moved on.  A lot of things have changed and while I don't notice this issue right now, I haven't done any benchmarking to verify.  Even if I did, it couldn't tell you what changed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As drexin mentioned, what resource settings are used in the case of marathon and chronos? There shouldn't be a difference since in both cases the image is downloaded and the mesos containerizer will be called directly.

Comment: I used the same settings for both.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using the default resources, which I believe for Chronos is 0.1 CPUs and 256MiB of memory. Try increasing this to 1 CPU and 1024MiB of memory.

Comment: I already set the CPU to 1, so that isn't the issue.  I did think it was a resource issues, to I upped the RAM to 4096 and there was no difference.